# Identifying duplicates in a large data set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have lists of SMS Messages that are sent on a weekly basis that are usually between 200-300,000 entries and I am trying to identify cases where an individual has had more than one message with the same Template ID

So for the sake of this the mobile number is in Column E and the Template ID is in Column K.

Thus far I have tried adding a helper column but excel does not have the resources to run it

To do this I have concatenated Column E & K and then used

```
=IF(COUNTIF($N$2:N2,N2)>1, "Duplicate","Original")
```

Unfortuntaely this is where Excel won't calculate all of this because it doesnt have enough resources.

Is there a more efficient way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: When it comes to duplicates I often use Conditional Formatting to highlight any duplicates, you can then filter/sort by cell colour. See [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Apply-conditional-formatting-with-color-in-Excel-34402f91-c7e7-4060-944c-65d913033d18) for more info.

Comment: Maybe import the data into Access and use SQL - not so sure on using SQL in Excel, but that could also be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a pivot table.
Use your column N as *Rows* and a count of the same column as *Values*. You can then sort on the row label based on the value to only see those with value > 1.

**EDIT**

Since you are unable to concatenate. The following should work:

- Set Mobile Number as Row label.
- Also set Template ID as Row label.
- Set Mobile Number as Value as well - and change the Value Field
  Settings so that it summarises by **Count**.
- Remove subtotals from Mobile Number by right clicking and adjust the 
  layout as you feel is best (I would go for Tabular).
- Then filter Template ID by *value* greater than 1.

Comment: Column N unfortuntaely crashes Excel when I copy it down as it does not have sufficient resources - is there another way around it with simply the source data?

I can achieve a Pivot using Mobile Number and Count of  'Date Sent' as Value - but I cannot filter the Count of 'Date Sent' as it tries to filter based on date than the value it returns (i.e. if i wanted to show >2)

Comment: Ah, I see. I was under the impression that you were able to concatenate in column N. You could try to achieve that via VBA and then use the pivot table. How are your VBA skills then?

Comment: I've gone back and edited the answer to work without the concatenate column. Check your pivot and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

No need to concatenate.  Just use `COUNTIFS`

Try this formula for conditional formatting

```
=COUNTIFS($E$2:E2,E2,$K$2:K2,K2) > 1
```

Or, this for your original plan:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($E$2:E2,E2,$K$2:K2,K2)>1,"duplicate","original")
```

If that doesn't work, perhaps a VBA solution would work, but I haven't tested this on very large data sets.